# How to run a Selenium NUnit test using Windows Authentication with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-authentication, iis-express

Our web app requires Windows Authentication. I have a NUnit test that

1. Launches a IIS Express process hosting my web app.
2. Starts up a `FirefoxDriver` and navigates to the web app.

Unforntunately it gets a `401.0 - Unauthorized` error without even asking for credentials. I'm used to Firefox asking for credentials in which case you can add

```
        profile.SetPreference("network.ntlm.send-lm-response", true);
        profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "localhost");
```

but for some reason, I just get a 401 right away with **Logon User**: *Anonymous*.

How can I tell Selenium/Firefox to use integrated security? Looking at the Windows Task Manager, I see that the Firefox process is started "as me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh. I was editing the wrong `applicationhost.config`. On a 64-bit OS the relevant config file is `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config` (not `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config` which to my misfortune also exists).

Therein, I have enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication. Then Firefox started asking for credentials, and then I could set the `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` in the profile passed to the `FirefoxDriver` as outlined it my question.